# How to change A-record without ISP Manager

Tags: linux, dns

I try to configure VDS server to run 3 PHP sites ( Debian Wheezy ). I choose the bundle Nginx + php-fpm + mysql. I can't understand how to change A-record, so domain name will point to my new VDS.

The domains registered on domain registrator, not on my hosting provider, so from there I only could change DNS. I already done this, because both VDS is on the same hosting provider.

On the previous VDS I have ISP Manager, and it's quite easy to change records from there. But is it possible to change records without any panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to a cPanel or the like, it is very difficult to change an A record, or any other record for that matter.

If by some chance you have access to the DNS server for your domain, you could ssh to telnet to it and configure Bind (or AD DNS directly).

Best option here is to contact your hosting provider as they really should provide you with an option to manage your DNS records. At the very least, they should be able to change or add records for you, if you explain to them via email or phone.